# How do I fill the value of a dom node input with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How do I fill the value of a dom node input with Mechanize?

I want the website to show a range of trucks manufactured from 2010 upwards so I can parse the relevant information.

There is no actual form involved.

This is the code:

```
require "mechanize"

@url = "https://www.kleyntrucks.nl/vrachtwagens/trekker/"

a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
end

a.get(@url) do |page|

    bouwjaar_range_field = page.search("#imprp0")

    bouwjaar_range_details = bouwjaar_range_field.search(".details")

    input = bouwjaar_range_details.search("input")[0]

    input.value = "2010"

end
```

This is the output:

```
/Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/folder/lib/tasks/experiment.rb:20:in `block in <main>': undefined method `value=' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007fd4ab0fd9a8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:442:in `get'
    from /Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/folder/lib/tasks/experiment.rb:10:in `<main>'
[Finished in 1.9s with exit code 1]
```

`pp input` gives me the following output:

```
#(Element:0x3fe33c82ab68 {
  name = "input",
  attributes = [
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c869430 { name = "type", value = "hidden" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c8692a0 { name = "name", value = "slider_from" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c869278 { name = "value", value = "1968" })]
  })
```

`puts input` gives me the following output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="slider_from" value="1968">
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

What I want it to do:

1. Visit https://www.kleyntrucks.com/trucks/tractorunit/
2. Set "MATRICULATION YEAR" (iow year of manufacture) to the range of 2010 and 2014
3. Scrape information about all the trucks that are listed (and are manufactured between 2010 and 2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `input.value = "2010"`

to

```
input['value'] = "2010"
```

`type`, `name` etc are the attributes of the `input` element. You need to use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#[]=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method for the same.

Read the documentation of [`[]=(name, value)`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

> Set the attribute value for the attribute ***name*** to ***value***

**Example :**

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML <<-xml
<foo atr = '123'> test </foo>
xml

doc.at('foo')['atr'] # => "123"
doc.at('foo')['atr'] = "999"
puts doc
```

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo atr="999"> test </foo>
```

Comment: Thank you Arup, this works for `pp input` now shows the correct value. But when I do `puts page.content` after that the input value is still `0`. Any ideas? I want the website to show a range of trucks manufactured from 2010 upwards so I can parse the relevant information.

Comment: @narzero `page.search("#imprp0")` gives you a `Nokogiri::HTML` or `Nokogiri::XML` Document. And with that parsed document object, you did the changes. But `page` is simply a [`Mechanize::Page`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-search) object. Thus the changes will not be present `page.content`, rather do `puts bouwjaar_range_field`, you can see the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I do see the change now, but I just see the HTML from `page.search("#imprp0")` and it does not contain the truck information I need. How can I make sure that it does include the value of `2010` and all the page information?

Comment: @narzero I think, as per your post error, I answered, I think you can accept it. For your new need, please post a different question.

Comment: I agree. Great answer.